# How do you change a GitHub Package Registry description on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-package-registry

When you publish a Package on GitHub Package Registry, you can optionally create a description of the Package. Unfortunately, I wrote a description that no longer adequately describes the code in the repo. How do I change the description?

There is no edit option for the published packages? Also, there is no versioning for that file. Every time you need to freshly create and that too only in the GitHub web app?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, I see an option pops in a week to edit without changing any access.

[image]